# Wordpress : Page not found when parameter "paged" is set

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I started a new WordPress website, with a theme from scratch. The goal is to use twitter bootstrap and have a lightweight site.

I have a problem when I set a pagination with WP-PageNavi for exemple. When I go on the next page, WordPress return me a "Page Not Found". I realized that the var `$paged` is set to `0` whatever the page I am.

Then, it looks like the `query_var 'paged'` don't work ...

Thanks by advance for your help :).

Here's my code :

> $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
>
> $args = array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'category__in' => array($category->term_id), 'paged' => $paged);
>
> query_posts($args);
>
> ?>
>
> ```
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-md-8">
>
>     <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
>
>       <div class="post">
>         <div class="thumb-post">
>           <div class="date">
>             <div class="day"><?php the_time('d') ?></div>
>             <div class="month"><?php the_time('M') ?></div>
>           </div>
>           <div class="thumbnail crop">
>             <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
>               <img src="<?php echo get_first_image(); ?>"/>
>             </a>
>           </div>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="post-content">
>           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
>             <h2 class="post-heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
>           </a>
>
>           <div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>
>     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
>
>     <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
>
>   </div>
> ```

I think that the problem start before that code. Because he return me a "Page Not Found" error .

Comment: In wp-admin->settings->reading, do you have the correct number of 'Blog pages show at most' set?

Comment: Yes, but I mostly use ‘query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'category__in' => array($category->term_id), 'paged' => $paged)); ?>‘

Comment: @FlorianMithieux Can you post the code you're using for the query in full?

Comment: Of course, I edit my post for more clarity !